# Tab page is closing when deleting buffer

Tags: neovim, buffers, linux, tabbed-user-interface

I'm using [`bufferline.nvim`](https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim) in order to display both buffers and tab pages on the tabline, whenever i delete a buffer with `bd`, all the buffers on that tab page are deleted as well, alongisde with the tag page itself, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of neovim with tabs]

If i recall correctly, when deleting a specific buffer, only this buffer should be deleted and the tab page should remain opened alongside the other buffers that were already present on that given tag page

How do i prevent such behavior from happening?

#### Additional Information

**neovim:**

```
NVIM v0.5.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_TS_HAS_SET_MATCH_LIMIT -O2 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wshadow -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fno-common -fdiagnostics-color=always -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -D_GNU_SOURCE -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -I/build/neovim/src/neovim-0.5.1/build/config -I/build/neovim/src/neovim-0.5.1/src -I/usr/include -I/build/neovim/src/neovim-0.5.1/build/src/nvim/auto -I/build/neovim/src/neovim-0.5.1/build/include
Compiled by builduser

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
```

**OS:** GNU/Linux (Arch Linux) 5.15.2-arch1-1 x86_64

**dotfiles:** https://github.com/henriquehbr/dots/tree/main/.config/nvim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved on [r/neovim](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/qxijg9/comment/hl9oual/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

> A tab will close when the last window is closed. A window will close when the buffer currently occupying it is deleted. This is default behavior. Tabs are collections of windows, that's how Vim handles them, if you want to keep a tab open you must have one or more windows for that tab